# uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Given the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ does the series converge on $\mathbb R$? I found that the radius is $\infty$ and I know that for $\forall c\in [0,\infty)$ the sum converges uniformly **in [-c,c]**. Does it mean the sum converges uniformly on all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DonAntonio question was edited. Lord_Farin, I will take it into consideration.

Comment: Well, after the editing my past comment makes no sense any more. Anyway, mrf already made clear what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $f_k \to f$ uniformly, then $(f_k)$ must be uniformly Cauchy, i.e for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $K$ such that $\sup|f_j-f_k| < \varepsilon$ for every $j,k \ge K$.

In your case, $$f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_{k+1}-f_k| = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \frac{|x|^{2k+3}}{(2k+3)!} = \infty
$$
for every $k$.

(In fact, a similar reasoning shows that a sequence of polynomial can never converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to something other than a polynomial.)

Comment: fix me if i'm mistaken but cauchy uniform convergence is $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists K s.t |f_j-f_k|<\epsilon \forall j,k\geq K$ (without the sup)... am I wrong?

Comment: Your inequality should hold for *all* $x$ (so it's the same as putting a ''$\sup$'' there.

Comment: but how do you that the function gets maximum ( in oanother way: $\exists x_0=\max_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x)$)?